# Personal Intranet Setup - how to disable it - after having enabled it

Tags: windows, security, iis, networking, intranet

I make web apps, which I even put in my wwwroot folder of IIS. I decided one day I wanted to be able to see the web apps performing (and how they appear) from my other computers. So, one night I went on a determined search on how to set this up not stopping until I accomplished it. So, I was able to set it up. The thing is I was thinking about this setup the other day, and realized its actually a very insecure setup, and would rather disable it as it is now. I have recently read that using a VPN with certain settings is more secure. But, I am not here to ask what would be the most secure way to go about this, although suggestions on that could come handy too. But, I would really appreciate some help in figuring out how to disable my current intranet. I have Windows 8 and IIS 8. I also have done these things which I did based on doing the opposite of what I could find doing a couple quick google searches:

- I went into the Allow an App through Windows Firewall window, and went to the selection of World Wide Web Services (HTTP), which was checked - like is suggested on some sites to have selected to enable an intranet - and I unchecked it and disabled it.
- I went into IIS, and chose default website, and went to Bindings, which, other than the default binding of port 80, had a binding to a port number. I removed this binding.
- I restarted my computer after doing these things.

So, I've done these things, and I haven't effected it, it still loads the webpages on other computers in my network as if I had done nothing. I feel helpless at this point, and so I came here to ask about this hoping someone might suggest something that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few days waiting for a reply from somebody here, I tried to see if there was anything else that I could do on my own. I was going to go back online hoping to find some other advice elsewhere, but then something came in my mind - maybe the fix for this problem is so simple it was under my nose all along - maybe if I simply uninstalled IIS it'd reset the installation.

So, I did just that, uninstalled IIS and then reinstalled it. It did reset it, and it works just fine on my computer, and not on any other computers - just as I wanted. I should've tried this all along! So, if anyone else stumbles on this page, and has enabled an insecure intranet and couldn't figure out how to disable it (like I was in the predicament of), if you haven't tried uninstalling and reinstalling IIS - try it - it should work.

Now, although I have a better idea of what a more secure intranet should be (as I mentioned above), I just thought it might be a good idea to ask people here on stackoverflow for there suggestions and opinions on how to go about that on another question post.